# What fonts are used in the video game Hades?

Tags: font-identification, games

Image attached. More specifically for the character names (white text) and dialogues. I have tried using Font Matcherator but it failed to properly identify because the image has a low resolution. (I couldn't find any high-resolution versions of this image).[image]

Comment: I wouldn't be too surprised if the Greek-look font for the character names turned out to be a custom creation rather than a publicly available font.

Comment: @Vincent I remember reading a post (I think that it was on Reddit) somewhere that all fonts on this game are on Google fonts. But I don't know when.

Comment: if you're sure it's google fonts you could go there and try scrolling for a while...

Comment: try: `{game install directory}\Content\Win\Fonts\en`

Comment: @Yorik While I have a PC, I don't own a copy of this game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are located in the folder `{game install directory}\Content\Win\Fonts\en`

We can see the package listing for the game via steamDB: https://steamdb.info/depot/1145361/

I think they are all open source, and according to the Steam package, they are:

```
AlegreyaSansExtraBold
AlegreyaSansExtraBoldItalic
AlegreyaSansItalic
AlegreyaSansRegular
AlegreyaSansSCBold
AlegreyaSansSCExtraBold
AlegreyaSansSCLight
AlegreyaSansSCMedium
AlegreyaSansSCRegular
AlegreyaSCBold
AlegreyaSCBoldTracking
AlegreyaSCRegular

CaesarDressing
CaesarDressingTitling

CrimsonTextBoldItalic
CrimsonTextItalic
CrimsonTextRoman
CrimsonTextRomanCondensed
CrimsonTextSemibold

FellType
FellTypeCondensed
FellTypeItalic

Garamond

MonospaceTypewriterBold

SpectralSCBold
SpectralSCExtraLight
SpectralSCLight
SpectralSCLightTitling
SpectralSCMedium

UbuntuMono
UbuntuMonoBold
```

The above are the english tree. There are other folders for other languages.

Comment: Thank you very much! And I suspect that most of these fonts are from Google fonts, right?

Comment: The first two are. I didn't follow up beyond that.

Comment: Nice find! To save anyone else the trouble, the fonts used in OPs image are [Caesar Dressing](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Caesar+Dressing) for the character names, [Alegreya Sans SC](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Alegreya+Sans+SC) for the character title, and [Alegreya Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Alegreya+Sans) for the dialog.

Answer (score 2):

The body text font is a humanist sans-serif but not one I recognize. It looks like some Erik Spiekermann families like FF Meta and Fira Sans. Although it isn't either of those, they might be good to look at if you want something similar. Here's Fira Sans Condensed Bold.
[image: Sample of Fira Sans]
Fira Sans is an open-source family available for free download [here](https://github.com/bBoxType/FiraSans). You can also get [FiraGO](https://github.com/bBoxType/FiraGO), an expansion that covers more writing systems, but it doesn't include condensed weights. It's based on FF Meta, which was designed for printed media and might be better on high-quality screens or at larger sizes.